# Как различать в строке пробел JAVA

Tags: java

Здраствуйте. Хочу при вводе данных вида: `"privet kak dela"` машина разделяла Строку на слова: `"1 = привет; 2 = как; 3 = dela"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Используй `yourString.split(" ")`

Answer (score 1):

Регулярное выражение может быть другим, в зависимости от ваших потребностей:

```
yourString.split("\\s+");
yourString.split("[,;:.!?\\s]+"); //учитывая пробелы, и символы, которые  могут разделять слова.
```

Вы можете использовать не только split, но и StringTokenizer со своей регуляркой. Пример:

```
String s = "Какой-то ваш текст, ывва , шнгщш? ... ";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, "\t\n\r,.");
while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
        System.out.println(st.nextToken());
    }
```

Другой вариант написать самостоятельно разбиение на символы и слова по своему алгоритму.